# Random numbers error in scan, theano.gof.fg.MissingInputError

Tags: python, theano

I have a small problem using random numbers together with scan.

Please see this small example in which I tried to isolate my problem.

```
import theano as th
import numpy as np
from theano import tensor as T

stream=th.tensor.shared_randomstreams.RandomStreams()

avg = T.vector()

initial_values = np.array([1,2,3,4,5], dtype=th.config.floatX)
initials = th.shared(initial_values)

def get_output(prev_rand):
    rand = stream.normal(size=prev_rand.shape, avg=prev_rand.mean())
    random_fn = th.function([], rand)
    random_numbers = random_fn()
    return random_numbers

result, updates = th.scan(get_output, outputs_info=[initials], n_steps=10)

f = th.function([], result)

print f()
```

What this code should do is the following:
- begin with an array, in this case [1,2,3,4,5]
- generate random numbers sampled from the normal distribution with the average being the average of the previous output (or the initial observations)
  In this case the average for the first step would be 3.
- Let's say the sampled numbers are: [2,3,3.5,4,5], the new average is now 3.5
- Repeat the above for 10 timesteps

Instead I get the following error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 585, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:/Users/Main/Documents/Python Scripts/untitled13.py", line 24, in <module>
    result, updates = th.scan(get_output, outputs_info=[initials], n_steps=10)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\scan_module\scan.py", line 737, in scan
    condition, outputs, updates = scan_utils.get_updates_and_outputs(fn(*args))
  File "C:/Users/Main/Documents/Python Scripts/untitled13.py", line 21, in get_output
    random_numbers = th.function([], rand, givens={avg:rand})
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function.py", line 265, in function
    profile=profile)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\pfunc.py", line 511, in pfunc
    on_unused_input=on_unused_input)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 1545, in orig_function
    on_unused_input=on_unused_input).create(
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 1224, in __init__
    fgraph, additional_outputs = std_fgraph(inputs, outputs, accept_inplace)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 141, in std_fgraph
    fgraph = gof.fg.FunctionGraph(orig_inputs, orig_outputs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\fg.py", line 135, in __init__
    self.__import_r__(outputs, reason="init")
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\fg.py", line 257, in __import_r__
    self.__import__(apply_node, reason=reason)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\fg.py", line 353, in __import__
    detailed_err_msg)
theano.gof.fg.MissingInputError: A variable that is an input to the graph was neither provided as an input to the function nor given a value. A chain of variables leading from this input to an output is [<TensorType(float32, vector)>, Shape.0, Elemwise{Cast{int32}}.0, RandomFunction{normal}.1]. This chain may not be unique
Backtrace when the variable is created:
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 585, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:/Users/Main/Documents/Python Scripts/untitled13.py", line 24, in <module>
    result, updates = th.scan(get_output, outputs_info=[initials], n_steps=10)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\scan_module\scan.py", line 597, in scan
    arg = safe_new(init_out['initial'])
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\scan_module\scan_utils.py", line 75, in safe_new
    nw_x = x.type()
```

I am probably missing something simple and obvious again here.

Help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the updates dictionary that you get form scan to your function, so:

```
f=th.function([initials], result, updates=updates)
```

Also, you can't have shared variables as input to your function.

You can achieve what you are trying to do for example like this:

```
import theano as th
import numpy as np
from theano import tensor as T

stream=th.tensor.shared_randomstreams.RandomStreams()

avg=T.vector()
initials=T.fvector()

def get_output(prev_rand):
    return stream.normal(size=prev_rand.shape, avg=prev_rand.mean())

result, updates = th.scan(get_output, outputs_info=[initials], n_steps=10)

f = th.function([initials], result, updates=updates)

initial_values = np.array([1,2,3,4,5], dtype=th.config.floatX)

print f(initial_values)
```